# Entity Framework Foreign Key Error with Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

We have an MVC project using Entity FrameWork where we have three tables, a class table, a student table and a teacher table. Teacher and student tables have relationship with class table by CLASS_ID. We are trying to make a copy of a class and insert it to database along with its teachers and students.

```
public void MakeClassCopy(int classID){

    var copiedClass = database.TABLE_CLASS.Where(x => x.ID == classID).First();

    var students = copiedClass.TABLE_STUDENTS.ToList(); //Lines that cause the exception
    var teachers = copiedClass.TABLE_TEACHERS.ToList(); //Lines that cause the exception

    database.TABLE_CLASS.Add(copiedClass);
    database.SaveChanges(); 
    string newTableID = copiedClass.ID;

    //Insert students and teachers with new CLASS_ID here

}
```

This method works if we omit the problematic lines, but when executed like this, we get a runtime exception saying

```
"The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'TABLE_CLASS.ID' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'TABLE_STUDENTS.CLASS_ID' on the other end."
```

Why are we getting this error only by defining two variables? We don't even use them in any other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By selecting the students and teachers of the 'copiedClass', you're actually selecting those of the class with class_id 'classId' into the database context. Those objects remain in memory.
Next you probably change the class_id of those objects, and insert them into the database. All is well until the insert is finished and the cache tries to update. This cache has a reference to all those fetched objects, but with different class_id's.
The students you fetched with the ToList, are now linked to another class and that's not consistent with the context.

When copying objects, you have 2 clean options:
 1. create new objects, copy properties of the previous objects and insert them
OR
 2. use the first context to fetch the objects, and a 2nd context to insert the new objects